# Отслеживание вывода команды ping

Tags: python

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['ping', '8.8.8.8'])
```

Выполняю команду пинг и пытаюсь получить каждый следующий пинг в новый элемент массива. Пинг идет непрерывно, хочу отслеживать время и если оно превышает заданное значение выводить на экран `False`.  Скажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

Comment: У этой команды есть опция таймаута, читайте документацию. Я думаю, будет удобнее использовать готовые инструменты для питона. Что-то вроде этого https://github.com/alessandromaggio/pythonping

Comment: тут принципиально надо использовать subprocess. Идея в том, что пинг будет работать без таймаута, в случае снижения пинга должно происходить действие в случае повышения пинга, должно происходить другое действие. Но принципиально надо использовать subprocess

Comment: Смотрите этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/7485582. У меня на виндовз такая программа получилась https://ideone.com/3JuVqF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess, re


def ping(*args, ping_timeout=5):
    """при превышении 'время<1мс' более ping_timeout вернет False иначе время мс"""
    with subprocess.Popen(['ping', *args], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) as proc:
        for out in proc.stdout:
            s = out.decode('cp866', 'ignore')  # Ответ от 127.0.0.1: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=128
            if 'Ответ от' in s:
                t = re.findall(r'\d+', s)  # ['127', '0', '0', '1', '32', '1', '128']
                p_time = int(t[-2])  # 1
                yield False if (p_time > ping_timeout) else p_time
            elif 'Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.' in s:
                yield False


for out in ping('127.0.0.1', ping_timeout=1):  # , '-t'
    print(out)  # int or False
```